# updateAttribute() function is not working on order attribute

Tags: upgrade, sales-order, eav, setup-script

i  am trying to update an sales order  attribute default using  updateAttribute()  function

But it is not working.

**code is here:**

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup */

$installer->startSetup();
$installer->updateAttribute('order', 'is_local',  array('default'=>0));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Can anyone tell me,IS `updateAttribute`()  function is not working on sales order field magento 1.9 CE?

Comment: Are you trying to update a column in sales_flat_order table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;

$definition = 'INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0';
$installer->getConnection()->modifyColumn(
    $installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'is_local', $definition
);
```

You should of course modify `$definition` to fit your needs.