# Update order attribute

Tags: attributes, orders

I have an order attribute set by a community extension that works fine in admin but I need to use it from frontend too but I don't get it, I think is because is set like this in `mysql4-install-0.3.0.php`

```
$this->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('order', 'atribute_name', array(
    'type'          => 'varchar',
    'label'         => 'Atribute Label',
    'visible'       => false,
    'required'      => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'user_defined'  =>  false
));
$this->endSetup();
```

How do I update it? I tried adding a update mysql 0.4.0 script and update the version without luck, also is there any other reason I get it empty from frontend.

Comment: Can you paste your config.xml and the update script?

Comment: on the update script I just copy/paste the install script with visible_on_front true, as per config I just bumped the version

Comment: Did you mean product attribute in your question?

Comment: No, I updated to code

Answer (score 2):

Order attributes don't have an is_visible or is_visible_on_front setting. Those are exclusive to products. To make a particular order attribute appear on the frontend, you have to modify the appropriate template (after copying it to your theme, don't modify default/base) to expose that attribute.

Comment: Just that $order->getAttributeName Works fine on phpunit or admin but can't get it from logged in frontend user, I need it inside an event.

Comment: Perhaps the collection is loading only specific attributes then. You would need to modify that collection to call addFieldToSelect("attribute_code")

Comment: is a new order event, has nothing to do with collections, products

Comment: Can you update your question with some more context on what you are trying to do (along with some code)

Answer (score 0):

From Magento 1.4,`Mage_Sales` Module has been convert to `Flat structure from Eav Structure`.So if you was failed to update sales order field.

Even you  will try using  [updateAttribute()](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/52560/4564)

For this case, you need to use basic  **mysql Alter query**  for update `any field of sales Module at Database`